# How to write an article in css and html

Tags: html, css

How to write a consistent article that contains commas and lines under each other in css

```
<p> hhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh.
    kkkkkkkkkkkkk , ssssssssss .
    fffffffffffff. 
</p>
```

It shows one block without breaks and no spaces in this way 
hhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh.kkkkkkkkkkkkk , ssssssssss .fffffffffffff.

Comment: You need to use the correct HTML tags, `<br>` for example is a line break.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `pre` element which defines preformatted text and preserves both spaces and line breaks, but excluding the `p` element otherwise that's not valid HTML.

```html
<pre>
    hhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh.
    kkkkkkkkkkkkk , ssssssssss .
    fffffffffffff. 
</pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use article tag and inside article tag, you can use p tag to define the paragraph.

```
<article>
<p> text text</p>
</article>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use pre tags or br tags for line break

Comment: What does this add that the other answer doesn't cover?